# Automatically generating XML schemas using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xml-namespaces

Following this [tutorial](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Tutorials/XmlSchemas/XsdTutorial_04.aspx) I've refactored my 733 line schema into 16 separate files or sub-schemas, each with its own namespace. Now the top level schema is just 77 lines. The plan is to use these sub-schema's to build other top-level schemas.

The problem is that most top level schema's are quite similar and only differ in a few low level details. For example while one top level schema supports all `PaymentMethodType`'s (see [tutorial](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Tutorials/XmlSchemas/XsdTutorial_04.aspx)) another top-level schema may support only VISA and MasterCard. Currently my method of creating top-level schemas involves considerable duplication. For example, my current method of creating a top-level schema in which only VISA and MasterCard are supported would involve duplicating `Main.xsd` and `OrderType.xsd`, but customizing `CommonTypes.xsd` and reuse `CustomerTypes.xsd`. (As my actual schema is a lot longer a lot more duplication is involved.)

I find this duplication unacceptable primarily because it introduces a maintenance challenge i.e. I would have to maintain any number of identical sub-schemas with different names.

What I would like to know is if there is a method of automatically generating a schema without via a config file of some sort (XSLT perhaps?), in order to avoid duplicating sub-schemas.

Also, is it good practice for all the sub-schemas to declare the same target namespace in this case (just like the xml schema namespace `xs`, but have custom sub-schemas declare a separate namespace?

Comment: Have considered this situation at length myself, but never devised an elegant method of doing so. Will watch this thread with interest.

Comment: In that case you may want to keep an eye on the following thread as well:
http://www.oxygenxml.com/pipermail/oxygen-user/2012-November/004455.html

Answer (score 0):

Why are you duplicating `Main.xsd` and `OrderType.xsd` instead of reusing them as you do `CustomerTypes.xsd`? If they are literally identical (as "duplicate" implies), why not just import them? I'm guessing you might be omitting something from the question...

Also, there seems to be a word missing in "generating a schema without via".

1. Having a different namespace for each sub-schema will work; another approach is "chameleon schemas". This is where the sub-schemas don't have a namespace themselves, but take on the namespace of the toplevel schema. [Multi-Schema Project:
   Zero, One, or Many Namespaces?](http://www.xfront.com/ZeroOneOrManyNamespaces.html). However, this technique is a bit tricky, and not all tools support it, so some [suggest avoiding it](http://www.kohsuke.org/xmlschema/XMLSchemaDOsAndDONTs.html#avoid_chameleon). But for your case, maybe it's worth it... Certainly, reading those links will give you ideas about how to handle your situation.
2. You can [redefine](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#modify-schema) specific parts of another schema (with the rest of that schema being unchanged). Have a look at the [example below the defintion](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#modify-schema). This sounds like it's *exactly* the solution to your problem.  The redefined parts can be low-level, that are used by other parts of the schema (or other imported schemas). However, as with (1) above, this is a tricky part of the spec, which some tools might not support.

So... hopefully your tooling implements these features of the spec (and the tooling of anybody else who needs to use them).  You can test it with the example in the link above (I confirmed it works with xmllint).

If not, your idea of assembling the sub-schemas with XSLT (or other XML/text processing tool) would work.  If you want specific help with XSLT, I suggest you include samples of the schema you start with, and the resulting schema you want.

Answer (score -1):

I am not going to describe an XSLT based approach since I am not aware of any good one and because of the opening I see in your own wavering: “of some sort (XSLT perhaps?)”.

What you’ve wanted I’ve tried it back in 2004; I’ve abandoned XSLT as a language to use in dealing with XML Schema Refactoring, since I hold an opinion that schema object model APIs (SOM/XSOM) – APIs designed specifically for XSD analysis and creation – are a much more productive use of my time (for the XSLT pundit reading this, I’ve qualified my statement).

There’s always a possibility in that what you want is actually simple, hence a roll-your-own-XSLT-or-otherwise is feasible (economically or intellectually). Sharing more specific parameters for your problem may help yield better answers. Still, if you’re thinking about doing this professionally, i.e. with minimum assumptions about what your input and output XSDs will look like, you’re in for a bit of work.

What I ended up doing was designing a [Domain Specific Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) for XML Schema Refactoring. It is available as part of [QTAssistant](http://paschidev.com) XSR module.
Graphically, this is what your “733 line schema into 16 separate files or sub-schemas” could look like in QTAssistant.

[image]

Its refactoring features allow many of the things you described from a single source set. All you need to do is configure the “views” you want with whatever features needed (e.g. what goes in what XSD file, automatically pulling in required dependencies, change target namespaces, refactor names of types, elements, substitute base type remove unwanted particles, introduce sequence wrappers to change cardinality, etc.) A button push gets you guaranteed valid XSD files. It also comes with a command line interface for integration with automatic build systems.

If anything, I would consider looking at an API such as in .NET's [Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.aspx) package, if only to get inspiration on maybe how the XSLT templates may be designed...